# Matplotlib ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 20, not 0

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, keras, subplot, autoencoder

I'm following this tutorial of [Building Autoencoders in Keras](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) on MNIST handwritten digits.
Here is the code bellow:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# at this point the representation is (4, 4, 8) i.e. 128-dimensional

x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

After loading Mnist dataset and train our model, here we are going to plot our original and reconstructed images

```
decoded_imgs = autoencoder.predict(x_test)

n = 10
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 4))
for i in range(n):
    # display original
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i)
    plt.imshow(x_test[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    # display reconstruction
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + n)
    plt.imshow(decoded_imgs[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

I searched a lot to fix this problem without finding a solution, here is the error shown bellow:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-35-d0a536786436> in <module>()
      5 for i in range(n):
      6     # display original
----> 7     ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i)
      8     plt.imshow(x_test[i].reshape(28, 28))
      9     plt.gray()

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py in __init__(self, fig, *args, **kwargs)
     64                 if num < 1 or num > rows*cols:
     65                     raise ValueError(
---> 66                         f"num must be 1 <= num <= {rows*cols}, not {num}")
     67                 self._subplotspec = GridSpec(
     68                         rows, cols, figure=self.figure)[int(num) - 1]

ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 20, not 0

<Figure size 1440x288 with 0 Axes>
```

Comment: The `range(n)` returns a sequence of integer numbers starting from zero to `n-1`. However, `subplot` cannot take value of zero as one of its arguments. Hence, you should change it accordingly: `range(1, n+1)`, i.e. the `1` for starting from one and the `n+1` to make it end at  number `n` (not `n-1`). Therefore, all the numbers from 1 to 20 would be covered with using `i` and `i+n` in `subplot` calls.

Comment: yes it worked thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first loop, i==0 because `range(10)` is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.  You can't use 0 as an index for the subplots, which causes that error.  You should instead use `i+1` in your `plt.subplot()` to get the correct axis.